# Backbonejs app automatically loads page `?state=#users` when navigating to `#users`

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

In my *backbonejs* application, the app automatically reloads the page to `example.com/?stat=#users` when I navigate to `router.navigate('users')`?

When I hit the back button it loads the url `example.com/#users` so it is accessing the desired page correctly then loading `example.com/?stat=#users`.

What is the issues I am running into, I've tried changing the `trigger` options but I am unable to fix it?  And I am unable to find more information on what the `?state=#...` is (I can make assumptions but concise documentation would be very helpful)?

A stripped down routes file:

```
class window.AppRouter extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    "": "list"
    "users": "list"
    "user/:id": "userDetails"

  list: -> 
    @before()

  before: (callback) ->
    if @users?
      callback() if callback?
    else
      @users = new Users
      @users.fetch(
        success: ->
          $('#sidebar').html(new UsersView({model: app.users}).render().el)
          callback() if callback)

  userDetails: (id) -> 
    @before ->
      user = app.users.get( id)
      if user?
        console.log('inside if')
        app.showView( '#content', new UserView( {model: user}))

  showView: (selector, view) ->
    @currentView.close() if @currentView?
    $(selector).html(view.render().el)
    @currentView = view
    return view
```

My stripped down view file:

```
class window.UsersView extends Backbone.View
  tagName:'ul'
  className: 'nav nav-pills nav-stacked'
  initialize: ->
    @userViews = new Array
    @model.bind("reset", @render, this)
    @model.bind("add", (user) =>
      @$el.append( new UserInListView({model: user}).render().el))

  render: (event) ->
    _.each(
      @model.models
      (user) =>
        userView = new UserInListView( {model: user})
        @userViews.push( userView)
        @$el.append( userView.render().el)
      this)
    return this


class window.UserInListView extends Backbone.View
  tagName:"li"

  initialize: ->
    @template = _.template(tpl.get('user_in_list'))
    @model.bind("change", @render, this)
    @model.bind("destroy", @close, this)

  render: (event) ->
    @$el.html( @template( @model.toJSON()))
    return this

  events:
    "click a": "select"

  select: ->
    $("#sidebar>ul>li.active").removeClass("active")
    @$el.addClass( 'active')
    app.navigate("user/#{@model.id}", true)

class window.UserView extends Backbone.View
  initialize: ->
    templateName = 'user_edit'
    @template = _.template(tpl.get(templateName))
    @model.bind("change", @render, this)

  events:
    "click .cancel": "cancel"

  cancel: ->
    @remove()
    app.navigate('users', false)
```

I'm just not sure what is causing this, is it a binding? Is it twitter-bootstrap? Is it the way I set up my router?  How come when I access the url directly I don't run into issues but when my router navigates me there I do?

Comment: What is the code in `router's` `user` route's callback method ??

Comment: @Cyclone Ok, just expanded on the code.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is :(

Have you made `pushState : true` while initializing router ? If yes, can you try without that ?

And if `app.navigate('users', false)` is router navigation, then I don't think second parameter is not how it is passed, may be you can have a look at [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to with including a `name` attribute on an `<input>` or `<select>` tag [and I'm sure others], by including the attribute in the tag the attribute is included in get requests so when navigate is called it accesses the desired page but then performs the `GET` request with what ever the `name` parameter may be.

In my case, I left a `name='state'` in a selector (which I realized after accessing a user which actually had their `state` i.e. the state they live in set  and the url was `example.com/?state=IL#users` and this "state" was not pertinent to the state of the backbone page being accessed).